# anacron not working

Tags: ssd, trim, tmpfs, anacron

I have a clean install of Xubuntu 14.04 32-bit, and `anacron` doesn't seem to be working.

I read that it's better to use a cron job to trim SSDs, and that Ubuntu has a cron job to do that, so I removed discard from `/etc/fstab`. I wanted to confirm that the cron job was working, so I added an `echo` command to `/etc/cron.weekly/fstrim` so that it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# call fstrim-all to trim all mounted file systems which support it
echo "Trim started on" $(date) >> /home/dominic/Desktop/Trim_Runs
set -e
# This only runs on Intel and Samsung SSDs by default, as some SSDs with faulty
# firmware may encounter data loss problems when running fstrim under high I/O
# load (e. g.  https://launchpad.net/bugs/1259829). You can append the
# --no-model-check option here to disable the vendor check and run fstrim on
# all SSD drives.
exec fstrim-all
```

It runs fine from a terminal, but it never runs as a weekly job. So I moved it to `cron.daily`, but it never runs from there either. So I moved it to `cron.hourly`, and it does run every hour. The echo text appears in the file, and the drive light comes on for about two minutes. But `cron.hourly` does not use `anacron`.

Here is my `crontab` file. I have changed some of the times, but it didn't seem to work with the original times that came with Xubuntu either.

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
 PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 16   * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report      /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 1   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

I tested to see if it would run correctly from my user's crontab by putting the following into crontab -e. Then I waited a few minutes until 8:10 pm, but nothing happened.

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

10 20   * * *   test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
```

I think it must have the correct syntax for run-parts, because it does run when I move the script into `cron.hourly`.

It seems that `cron` is working but `anacron` is not. So my question is, what can I do to get `anacron` working?

Comment: Could you show us the relevant cron lines? There may be a syntax error. Also, `cron` (not sure about `anacron`) uses `run-parts` to run the scripts in `/etc/cron.weekly` and `run-parts` has some very strict requirements for script naming. Have a look at `man run-parts` for details (though it does look like that script should run OK). Also test whether it runs correctly from your own user's crontab (`crontab -e`).

Comment: Hi terdon - thanks for the response. I have added the information you asked for to the original question. I hope that was the right thing to do. I'm new here.

Comment: That is _exactly_ the right thing to do, thanks :). Whenever people ask for info in the comments, you should add the info to the question body and then reply (you can ping users with a `@`, for example to ping me just include `@terdon` in your comment) to the user who asked for it. Precisely as you did. I was hoping there was a syntax error but everything looks fine. I don't have any experience with anacron though. Why don't you add the command you want to run to your user's crontab? `* * * * * /path/to/fstrim`. That will launch it every minute and you can at least check that it works.

Comment: Why are you adding another script for trim? It is run automatically by ubuntu without the need of you fiddling with it.

Comment: Hi @Braiam. I didn't add another script. I just added an echo command to the existing script that came with Xubuntu. Then terdon suggested that I try crontab -e, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

I got anacron working on my system, as follows:

In `/etc/fstab` I have some directories moved to `tmpfs` to avoid writes to the SSD, like this:

```
tmpfs   /tmp       tmpfs   nodev,nosuid,noatime,mode=1777   0  0
tmpfs   /var/spool tmpfs   nodev,nosuid,noatime,mode=1777   0  0
tmpfs   /var/log   tmpfs   nodev,nosuid,noatime,mode=0755   0  0
```

This means that `/var/spool/anacron/` does not exist at boot time, and as a result, `anacron` does not function. The three files in this directory must be preserved across system boots for anacron to work. So I created a directory `/usr/local/etc/anacron/`, and at boot time I create `/var/spool/` and put a symlink in it that points to that directory. Now `anacron` is working because its three files (`cron.daily`, `cron.weekly`, and `cron.monthly`) are preserved across boots.

Actually, I create a bunch of directories at boot, as described here:
[How to fix anacron & cups-pdf when you have /var on tempfs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292377/how-to-fix-anacron-cups-pdf-when-you-have-var-on-tempfs) but I modified the script so that it doesn't create `/var/spool/anacron` but instead it creates the symlink mentioned above.

The resulting script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script to create required directories in tempfs /var/log (that are not otherwise created).
# This script is needed because I have some directories moved to tmpfs in /etc/fstab.
# That means these directories disappear every time I shut down.
# Programs should create them if they do not exist, but some, like anacron, fail to do   so, and then fail to run.
# So I create them here. I don't know where it gets the permissions from, or whether they are right.
# Thanks to http://blog.philippklaus.de/2011/02/ssd-optimizations-on-linux/ for the list below :-)

for dir in apparmor apt ConsoleKit cups dist-upgrade fsck gdm hp installer lightdm news ntpstats samba speech-dispatcher unattended-upgrades upstart; do
  if [ ! -d /var/log/$dir ] ; then
    mkdir /var/log/$dir
  fi
done

# And in /var/spool.
for dir in cups-pdf; do
  if [ ! -d /var/spool/$dir ] ; then
    mkdir /var/spool/$dir
  fi
done

# Create the symlink.
ln -s /usr/local/etc/anacron /var/spool/anacron
```

The above script is in my home directory and is run at boot time by a command in `/etc/rc.local` as described in the linked article.

Maybe the real solution to this problem would be for `anacron` to store `cron.daily`, `cron.weekly`, and `cron.monthly` in a directory that the user is not likely to move to `tmpfs`.